# Confused by "~奴らをあの連中~" in this sentence

Tags: particles, syntax, parsing

I was reading a passage from a novel and this exchange between two characters came up;

> Character A「もうほっといてもいいのに、レミーって時々ゆーじよーとか大事にするよねぇ？それとさ、部隊の残党を助けてるのって、半分は手駒にする為じゃなくって、あの療養所の人達への恩返しだったりしちゃうー？」
>
> Character B ( aka レミー)「知らねーな。足手纏いになりそうな奴らをあの連中に押しつけてるだけだ」

I think I have a general idea of what they're saying: A seems to be lightly teasing B saying B considers friendship as something important despite telling people to back off (もうほっといてもいいのに) and that they're gathering some of the 部隊 survivors as a repayment (in good will?) to the people in an infirmary.

But the 奴らをあの連中 part is in B's dialogue is particularly confusing. "I don't care. Those guys who are likely to be an obstacle  をあの連中に押しつけてる" I'm at a total loss as to how exactly one would parse this. I would simply expect a verb to follow the を and not something like あの連中, so I would like someone to explain how B's dialogue would be constructed into a sentence in English and why あの連中 immediately follows the を in this sentence.

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you a thorough explanation, but I will try to break it down for  you. You would parse this sentence like this:

> 足手纏いになりそうな奴らを / あの連中に / 押しつけてるだけだ

To make it easier for you to understand, you can rearrange this like the following:

> あの連中に / 足手纏いになりそうな奴らを / 押しつけてるだけだ

I would need more context to be sure of the meaning, but from what you have provided, I assume they are delivering the survivors to the infirmary? Also, I couldn't tell if you knew what 押しつける means by your question, so I'll go ahead and explain that as well.

> 知らねーな: While 知らない can mean "I don't care", here it's a little more natural-sounding to localize it to "Whatever" or "Like it matters".
>   足手纏いになりそうな奴ら: 足手纏いに / なりそうな / 奴ら = burden / likely to become / people = people who are likely to become a burden
>   あの連中に: to that group
>   押しつけてるだけだ: 押しつけてる / だけ / だ = push onto / only / (copula) = (someone) is just pushing (something) onto

Putting the sentence together, (someone) is pushing 足手纏いになりそうな奴ら onto あの連中. (someone1) is pushing [people who are likely to be a burden] onto [that group]. By context (since this is his response to A's remark), I gather that the someone1 = B.

And to sum it up into a localized version:

> Whatever. All I'm doing is forcing those who'll just drag me down onto those guys.

Or with more literary freedom:

> Whatever. All I'm doing is unloading extra baggage onto them.

This sentence structure cannot be recreated in English due to the nature of English sentence structures. The case markers に and を show the roles of the nouns, so it is possible to swap their order without changing the meaning of the sentence. The reason why あの連中に is placed later is to put more stress on 足手纏いになりそうな奴ら; that is the focus of the sentence, as opposed to あの連中. B wants to make it clear to A that these survivors are just extra baggage to him.

Answer (score -1):

You're halfway to the right answer when you say you'd expect a verb to follow を. The thing is that the verb is there, it's just being modified first:

> {あの連中に}押してつけてる = "pressing on that group (or lot/gang) of people"

For completion's sake, I might look at this sentence to mean:

> 足手纏いになりそうな奴らをあの連中に押しつけてるだけだ
>   All they are doing is being burdensome by pushing the lot of them.

EDIT: This newer translation might flow better in terms of meaning.